# How to define a Backbone.Collection to be a property but not an attribute of a Backbone.Model?

Tags: backbone.js

Say I have a web application which allows to filter a set of items and say that I'm using backbone.js in the web frontend.

Quite naturally I ended up creating a **Filter** which extends **Backbone.Model** and a **SearchResultList** extending **Backbone.Collection**. The Filter has some attributes like *searchTerm*, *dataFrom*, *dateTo*... Filter also has a method called `applyFilter`. `Filter.applyFilter` should call `searchResultList.fetch`, thus updating/filtering the search results.

The question is, how to best initialize `searchResultList` as a **property** of `Filter` instead of being an **attribute** in Backbone terms?

I would not like to create the `SearchResultList` in `Filter.initialize` as `SearchResultList` is not necessarily "owned" by `Filter`.

For now I ended up passing the `searchResultList` object as an `option` to `Filter.initialize`, but that feels a little bit awkward to me.

I doubt that it is a good idea to let `Filter.applyFilter` call `SearchResultList.fetch`. However, there needs to be a method of `Filter` which when called triggers a new request somehow. (Listening to change events of `Filter` is not an option either as the user is supposed to change filter options in multiple steps and decides to apply the filter manually via a button click)

Answer (score 0):

I have a Collection for performing searches. Most of my collections extend this Search Collection.

It has an object in it holding parameters for searching. The user of the collection can call `setSearchParam`, and I have a method `buildSearchString` that will build the search part of the URL to call (I use the Matrix parameters in my REST urls).

```
window.SearchCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({

  initialize : function() {
    this.params = {}; // holds parameters for searching
  },

  // Set a search param
  setSearchParam: function(param, value) {
    if (typeof value === 'undefined') return;
    if (typeof this.params === 'undefined') this.params = {};

    this.params[param] = value;
  },

  setSearchParams : function(paramMap) {
    _.extend(this.params, paramMap);
  },

  // Build Matrix params for search. This could just as easily be a standard URL string
  buildSearchString: function() {
    var search = [];
    var i = 0;

    for (var key in this.params) {
       var value = this.params[key];
       if (utils.isEmpty(value)) continue;

       search[i++] = ";";
       search[i++] = key;
       search[i++] = "=";
       search[i++] = value;

    }
    return search.join('');
  }
});
```

Then when I create a collection, I extend it:

```
window.BookingCollection = window.SearchCollection.extend({
    model: Booking,

    url: function(){

      var urlString = BASE_REST_URL + "bookings/";

      // Build the matrix params for the REST URL
      urlString += this.buildSearchString();

      return urlString;
    }

});
```

Then, a user of this collection can use it like so:

```
var bookings = new BookingCollection();
bookings.setSearchParam("name", "hello");
```